# Android java - Make notification at specified day in week

Tags: java, android

Hello i would like to trigger notification at exact day and time in week

what i did first i have created some checkboxes and textinputs for time hour and minute.

i will only paste the important part whis is :
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
for(int i = 0; i < dayNumbers.size(); i++){
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNumbers.get(i));
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),0, pendingIntent);
                    }
```

my broadcast receiver works but it triggers the alarm every day even tho i only choose which days should be trigered , the dayNumber arraylist contains the numbers of days for example sunday = 0 ...

how do i really restrict it to only run at the give day ? this triggers it every day.... thanks

Comment: Where you set 0 --> AlarmManager.INTERVAL_WEEK

Comment: what? what is that

Comment: Take a look at the RTC Examples here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
There is an alarm scheduled daily. You only have to set AlarmManager.INTERVAL_WEEK instead of AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
And set your calendar to the day of the week it shall trigger (for example sunday).

Comment: but i did it calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNumbers.get(i)); this sets to the number of day and i have edited 0 to AlarmMaanager.INTERVAL_DAY*7 in the method and it still triggers every day

Comment: With your for-loop you schedule 7 alarms!

Comment: wait why? dayNumber.size is the size of arraylist that contains numbers of days if user marks only one day in checkboxes it runs once and sets the daytofweek to that number and sets the alarm manager ... or?

Comment: but if the size of arraylist is 1 then it runs once ? what is wrong ? i dont understand now ? can we move this do discussion ? please i have to solve it as fast as possible

Comment: I dont understand what you try to do. If you want to set an alarm on a single day of the week: Remove the loop and set the calendar on the day of choice. if you want to set up multiple alarms in a week on different days then your loop is correct. The only thing you have to change is: alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),0, pendingIntent);
to  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_WEEK, pendingIntent);

Comment: yes i would like to repeat alarm every monday and friday for example, if the user choses 0 days it wont get repeated the loop is only trigered when user marks atleast one checkbox and i have changed it to alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent); but i still get it every day, the array list only contains one number when i ouput it to Log.d(); and it still triggers every day

Comment: Have you canceled your old alarms? Maybe there are still running some. Check if they're still scheduled. If so remove the app and install it again.

Comment: i just reinstalled the application and it still triggers every day

Comment: WAIT!  After this calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNumbers.get(i));
YOU SET THE ALARM AGAIN ON CURRENT DAY!
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: are days indexed from zero to six from sunday to saturday ? i always output the array and if the user marks sunday and monday it contains 0 and 1 i guess this works..

Comment: check out my last post

Comment: i have already removed that line above the alarmManager.setRepeating() but nothing changed i did it few mins ago

Comment: Then I cant help you. There must be something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: the setTimeInMillis should be after setting the minute hour and day ? or above ?

Comment: calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayNumbers.get(i));
                 
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);